# Youtube in iPhone blocks all click events after initiated

Tags: iphone, events, video, youtube, click

I am embedding a youtube iframe into a mobile slideshow which works fine up until someone clicks on the video, and it opens into it's native fullscreen support. After the video closes from fullscreen support, it leaves a some video elements inside the iframe which allows to resume the video, but blocks all other click events within the space of that iframe, meaning any elements that are z-indexed above that iframe are unclickable, and at the same time, none of my click events bubble up. Lastly, there's no way to access the DOM within that iframe since it's from a different origin.

Does anyone know of a way to access/disable this black void of a trap, whether it's some callback that is being called when it returns from fullscreen, or something else.

[image: Image Reference 1]

Image 2 is where the problem occurs

[image: Image Reference 2]

Comment: I was just about to post a question about this.. was grateful to see someone has come across this weird ios behavior.. but sad to see no attempt to answer this.. have you ever solved this?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing. Was forced to work around this issue...